# Не получается подключить Cufon

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, шрифты

Сайт на ASP.NET MVC,

На сайте меню такого вида

```
<ul class="site-nav sf-menu">
    <li @CurrentItem("Index")>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_Home, "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li @CurrentItem("WhoWeAre")>@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_WhoWeAre, "WhoWeAre", "Home")</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

в качестве названия пунктов меня выводятся значения полей из Global.resx (это изменить нельзя)

Из-за этого, когда подключаю Cufon к используемым в меню шрифтам

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/cufon-yui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Aller_400.font.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            Cufon.replace('ul.site-nav li a', { fontFamily: 'Aller', hover: true });
        });
    </script>
```

текст вообще пропадает.
Подскажите, каким образом можно решить эту проблему?

**UPD.** Пробую делать скрипт, чтобы Cufon срабатывал только после того, как загрузится весь контент меню

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var replace = function () {
        var gotinside = false
        $('ul.sf-menu').each(function (i) {
            gotinside = true;
            if (i < 1) {
                Cufon.replace('ul.sf-menu li a', { fontFamily: 'Aller', hover: true });
            }
        })
        if (!gotinside)
            setTimeout(replace, 1000);
    }
    replace();
});
```

но не срабатывает.
    </script>

Comment: 1. $(window).load заменить на $(document).ready
2. Cufon.replace('ul.site-nav li a' заменить на Cufon.replace('ul.sf-menu li a'

Comment: нет, первое уже была попытка применить, не прокатило, второе ни на что не влияет.

Comment: А если посмотреть в фаербаг - там есть какие-нибудь джаваскриптовые ошибки ?

Comment: нет, в скриптах ошибок нет. проблема в том, что контент, который должен обрабатывать куфон, подгружается динамически (см. апдейт)

Comment: Мне кажется здесь $('ul.sf-menu li ul li a') перебор с ul и li

Comment: с $('ul.sf-menu') тоже не работает

Comment: В своем предыдущем комментарии я имел в виду вместо $('ul.sf-menu li ul li a') написать $('ul.sf-menu li a') , а не убрать их вообще.

Comment: так тоже не работает, уже были пробы

Comment: Комментарий больше не могу добавить, поэтому пишу здесь. А если попробовать заменить `@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Global.Home_Menu_WhoWeAre, "WhoWeAre", "Home")` на `<a href="@Url.Action("WhoWeAre", "Home")">@Resources.Global.Home_Menu_WhoWeAre</a>`.

И еще такой вопрос - на сайте еще где-нибудь уже используется куфон ?

Comment: Завтра попробую ваш код, у меня из дома нет доступа к рабочему компу. Куфон на сайте используется только для этого меню, когда оно было статическим, то Куфон работал.

Comment: ну да, так тоже не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось, проблема была в не динамически подгружаемых пунктах меню, а в том, что шрифт Aller, используемый для Cufon, изначально не поддерживает кириллицу.